# Where is Laravel default logout function code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, logout

Can anyone tell me the location of the Laravel default logout function. The function that we get after running

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I checked web.php and it says its inside LoginController but I have checked it and there is nothing. So any idea where I can see the code of logout function? Thanks

Comment: It's in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers

Answer (score 2):

The default logout function for the web is in the following file

**\project_folder\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php**

and the function definition is

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/');
}
```

**But don't change here.**

You can override by making the same function under your LoginController.php file

**\project_folder\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php**

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
 */

protected function logout(Request $request)
{
    // do what ever you want.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see it in `resource > layouts > app theres a form there`.

and if you are looking for the routes it's in `Auth::routes()` by default you can check the vendor for the `auth`

You can also check the controller in `App > Http > Controllers > Auth > Login` and `ctrl + click` on `AuthenticatesUsers`.

or you can find it in vendor `vendor > laravel > ui > auth-backend > AuthenticatedUsers.php`